AttributeError: module 'conftest' has no attribute 'driver'
I'm trying to run the tests but I'm stuck with this error:
AttributeError: module 'conftest' has no attribute 'driver'

This is my code, Could someone tell me where the error is?
conftest
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

driver:webdriver.Remote


@pytest.fixture
def setup_teardown():
    #setup
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/")

    #run test
    yield

    #teardown
    driver.quit()

test login
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import conftest


@pytest.mark.usefixture("setup_teardown")
class TestCT01:
    def test_ct01_login_valido(self):
        driver = conftest.driver
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-name").send_keys("standard_user")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("secret_sauce")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-button").click()
        assert driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product_label").is_displayed()

Screenshot
Link

Just yield the driver instead of making it a global, directly reference the fixture in your test (and probably rename it to driver).

Your marker has missing 's' at the end that's why your test code is not triggering the fixture to initiate driver.
change your marker to:
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_teardown")
class TestCT01:

However, here is my suggestion that would be better for your situation:
1- You don't need to import conftest.py to your test code.
2- You don't need to have global variable for driver
conftest.py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture
def get_driver():
    #setup
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/")

    #run test
    yield driver

    #teardown
    driver.quit()

test_login.py
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class TestCT01:

    def test_ct01_login_valido(self, get_driver):
        get_driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-name").send_keys("standard_user")
        get_driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("secret_sauce")
        get_driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-button").click()
        assert get_driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product_label").is_displayed()


